# Running multiple tests one after other in TestNG

Tags: xml, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

I'm trying to automate scenario wherein, I need to navigate to website(which takes more than 30 seconds to load) then enter login details(again which takes 40 sec to load) then choose account tab in that and then need to modify some details in the account page.

Say, I made three class:

- Class1-Browser(Which has `@BeforeSuite`)
- Class2-Login
- Class3-AccountChange

```java
 public class Browser{

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("site_name");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void close(){
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I need to use `wait()` for Login class. I tried using all three `thread`, `implicitWait`, `explicitWait`. all throws the same error `NullPointerException`.

```java
public class Login extends Browser {

    @Test
    public void login(){
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("   ")));
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("    ")).sendKeys("Uname");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("    ")).sendKeys("Pwd");
    }   
}
```

I need to use wait for the below class too.

```java
public class AccountChange extends Browser {

    @Test
    public void change(){
        <<my code goes here>>
    }
}
```

XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Regression Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="pack.Browser" />
            <class name="pack.Login" />
            <class name="pack.AccountChange" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Please help.

**UPDATE:**
I'm explaining my criteria with gmail.

Using `@BeforeSuite` to open browser

```java
public class Browser {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void open(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/rjayavel/Documents/Selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Then using two classes for entering username and password.

```java
public class Username {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    @Test
    public void uname(){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("my_username");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span")).click();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Password {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void pwd(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("my_password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordNext']/content/span")).click();
    }
}
```

Then using `@AfterSuite` for signing out

```java
public class Signout {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @AfterSuite
    public void signout(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
    }
}
```

My XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="GMAIL">
    <test name="Login">
        <classes>
            <class name="gmail.Browserr"/>
            <class name="gmail.Username"/>
            <class name="gmail.Password"/>
            <class name="gmail.Signout"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here in the above case. First `@BeforeSuite` should run then it should wait for username locator to be visible then username should be typed followed by password and sign out function. But what actually happening was while executing `@BeforeSuite`, username and password are executing parallelly and throwing `NullPointerException` on wait command.

Error was as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at gmail.Username.uname(Username.java.14)
at org.testng.remote.abstractremotetestng.run(AbstractResmoteTestNG.java.114)
```

Same for password and sign out.

Hope you understand my situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the same, its working fine for me.

Comment: Really. But its throws NullPointerException error at the username locator line. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have shared doesn't have any pointers which would suggest that it is capable of throwing a `NullPointerException` because, you are initialising a `static` `WebDriver` reference in your `@BeforeSuite`. So even though your `@BeforeSuite` will run only once (mostly for the first class viz., `pack.Browser`), you are still safe, because its a static data member and static data members are shared across all instances of your test class (this is a recipe for many issues though).

So you would need to share the complete code, that when run is throwing the `NullPointerException` and maybe the stacktrace.

There are a couple of problems associated with your code.

1. You are initialising your webdriver reference for your class via a `@BeforeSuite` method. This will definitely cause `NullPointerException` for your classes in your `<test>` tag, when you include two or more `<class>` references in it because for the second `<class>` the `@BeforeSuite` doesn't get executed. You should change this annotation to instead use `@BeforeClass`. If you resort to using `@BeforeMethod` then you would need to switch over to a `ThreadLocal`variant, else your concurrent executions will be a problem.
2. You have a `static` `WebDriver`. Static data members are shared across multiple instances of the class. So if you later decide that you would like to have two or more `<class>` run in parallel using TestNG then you will literally see a race condition, because all your tests will try to operate on the same browser instance. You might want to remove the `static` attribute out of your data member.

**UPDATE (Based on the updated question)**

In your classes viz., `Password`, `Signout` and `Username` you have declared a webdriver instance `public WebDriver driver;`

This causes the `driver` data member from your base class `Browser` to be shadowed. To add to it, the data member in your classes `Password`, `Signout` and `Username` doesn't get initialised because of the shadowing act.

That explains the `NullPointerException`. Please remove this data member declaration in the classes `Password`, `Signout` and `Username`. That should resolve your `NullPointerException`. But in the long term, please address the two aspects that is called out above.

Comment: Please see my below answer. I explained my case in answer.

Comment: @Narmadha - Please edit your question and add this information instead of posting it as an answer because that can misguide others who might land on this question and looking for help.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now I added that information to my question. thanks for correcting me.
Could you please look into my scenario and help me with that?